# Using a Windows BIOS update on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, upgrade, bios, asus

I have an ASUS TUF A15 with a FA506IU BIOS, running Ubuntu 20.04. It's on version 304, and I've encountered some strange hardware issues. Someone suggested I update the BIOS, and, as per the [official ASUS site](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-A15/HelpDesk_Download/), they are up to version 313.

Now, that site prompts me for my BIOS name (which I happily provide) and my OS, which I list as "Others." That provides me with the option to download "FA506IV/IU/II/IH UL Certification." I have no idea what that is--I just want to update my BIOS. I check the Windows OS, and not only are there other downloads available, there is a "BIOS Update (Windows)" and a regular "BIOS" download at version 313.

I'm put off by the fact that these updates only appear when I select Windows as the OS. Am I able to download and install that update that is based on the Windows OS, or is there maybe some sort of different file system for Windows that will screw up the BIOS if I do that? How can I safely update the BIOS on my machine?

Comment: This is for Mint, but still of interest: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=277305

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIOS updates are meant for BIOS irrespective of the installed OS, so you should have chosen Windows as it's the only officially supported OS for your laptop.

> Am I able to download and install that update that is based on the Windows OS, or is there maybe some sort of different file system for Windows that will screw up the BIOS if I do that? How can I safely update the BIOS on my machine?

This update is offered as an `.exe` file, so I doubt you'll be able to install it under Linux, besides it might not be safe to even attempt to do so. And you'll need to find a way to run Windows on your laptop. Probably there are live Windows 10 DVDs floating around that you can boot from - that's probably what I'd do if I didn't have Windows installed but knowing about this intricacy I normally leave preinstalled Windows intact - I just shrink its partitions to be able to co-install Linux.

Lastly that's a question for https://superuser.com/questions

Comment: So two questions--firstly, there is a second file called "BIOS" which, when downloaded, is a binary named "FA506IU-AS.313". Can I use that to update the BIOS instead of the `.exe`? Secondly, why is this question more appropriate to _Superuser_ if the question is about a BIOS update specifically to a Linux machine?

Comment: I have a desktop ASUS motherboard and it allows to update BIOS from the BIOS. If such an option is available on your laptop, then download this file, place it into the root folder of any FAT32 partition and perform an update. This question is more pertinent for SuperUser because it has very little to do if anything with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

For my ASUS X751LB laptop (Windows free ;-) ), I downloaded the X751LBAS607.zip update from https://www.asus.com/fr/supportonly/X751LB/HelpDesk_BIOS/
extracted the X751LBAS.607 file to an USB key
Then reboot with USB key plugged and F2 key kept hold to enter setup menu to select the usbkey drive and file
launched the bios update
This was succesful
[image]